# Exactness of completion of topological abelian groups

Tags: topological-groups

Let $0\to G^{\prime}\to G\to G^{\prime\prime}\to 0$ be an exact
sequence of abelian groups. Suppose $G$ is a topological group and then
give topologies on $G^{\prime}$ and $G^{\prime\prime}$ which are
induced by the topology on $G$. If $H$ is topological abelian group, $\widehat{H}$  denotes its completion using Cauchy sequences.

> Is the sequence of completions
>   $0\to \widehat{G^{\prime}}\to \widehat{G}\to
> \widehat{G^{\prime\prime}}\to 0$
>   still exact as abelian groups?

For a topological abelian group $G$ with filtration of subgroups $G=G_0\supseteq G_1\supseteq
G_2\supseteq\cdots\supseteq G_n\supseteq \cdots$, if $\{G_n\}$ is a
basic system of neighborhoods of $0$, then 
from Corollary 10.3 of Atiyah's Introduction to
Commutative Algebra, we know that the above sequence
of completions is exact. So in general if the topology on $G$ is not
so good we don't have exactness of taking completion, and there will
exist many counterexamples, right? Could you provide an easy
counterexample or some references?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Here is an easy counterexample. The injective morphism $\mathbb{Z}\hookrightarrow \mathbb{Q}$ does not remain injective after, say, taking $p$-adic completions. In general, the completion functor for $R$-modules is neither left-exact nor right-exact, and need not be exact in the middle as well. It is only true that the completion functor preserves surjections. For more details see for example [here](http://arxiv.org/pdf/0902.4378v4.pdf).

Comment: Wait, doesn't the inclusion $\mathbb{Z} \hookrightarrow \mathbb{Q}$ extend to the inclusion $\mathbb{Z}_p \hookrightarrow \mathbb{Q}_p$ after completion?

Comment: No, see [here](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/147187/on-exactness-of-the-functors-m-mapsto-hatm-and-m-mapsto-hata-otimes).